# How to determine if a Storyboard is animating

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to develop an application that starts a Storyboard only if it's not animating.

Is there a way to determine if the Storyboard is animating or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Storyboard.GetCurrentState` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc672521.aspx) to check the `CurrentState` of the `Clock` that was created for the `Storyboard`. The possible values are `Active`, `Filling`, and `Stopped`. Note that the `Storyboard` *may* be paused, in which case, you need to check the [`Storyboard.GetIsPaused` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.getispaused.aspx) as well.