# C# Storyboard IF Statement

Tags: c#, blend

I have an issue whereby my program does not recognise a blend storyboard that I created. I named said storyboard "AlbumExitAndArtistEntrance" and when I try to use the following code, the program states that "The name 'AlbumExitAndArtistEntrance' does not exist in the current context.

```
private void lbl_sideBarArtists_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if (AlbumExitAndArtistEntrance)
   {

   }
   else
   {

   }
```

I haven't written this code yet, but I intend to detect when the storyboard has been run, and if it has, for it to automatically disable itself until an alternative storyboard has ran. I don't want to continue until the program recognises that my storyboard does exist, and works as intended when ran through VS Blend.

I hope to provide enough information with this question, since I am new to both c# and asking questions on stackoverflow. If I haven't, please use the below image to give you an idea of the look of my program.

[image]

Comment: In your code, you don't show the declaration of `AlbumExitAndArtistEntrance` - where is it declared? Also, the `if` statement expects a `boolean` value (e.g. either true or false).

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't declare it. Like I say, I am new to c#, so I thought that creating the storyboard in blend may have already declared it somehow; I've now declared it just underneath the "public partial class AlbumCatalogue : Window".

Comment: You are asking for 2 things: [detect if storyboard is running](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21041716/1997232) and [stop storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5623601/1997232).

Comment: is this a storyboard or a behavior containing a storyboard?

Comment: I'm trying to detect whether the AlbumExitAndArtistEntrance storyboard has been ran yet. I think @Sinatr could be correct with the links they have provided